# Print in scientific format with powers of ten being only multiples of 3

Tags: python, printing, scientific-notation, string.format

**I haven't found a way to only get exponents which are multiples of 3, when displaying numbers in the scientific format.** Neither did I succeed writing a simple custom formatting function.

Here is a quick example:
Normal behaviour using scientific notation with pythons `.format()`:

```
numbers = [1.2e-2, 1.3e-3, 1.5e5, 1.6e6]

for n in numbers:
    print("{:.E}".format(n))
```

```
>>> 1.20E-02  
    1.30E-03  
    1.50E+05  
    1.60E+06
```

I, however, need the following output:

```
>>> 12.00E-03   
     1.30E-03   
    15.00E+06  
     1.60E+06
```

Does anyone know a convenient way for me to get the desired formatting?

Comment: Actually, it won't be a scientific notation anymore, cause `12` is greater than `10`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it depends on if you want the output format to always adjust to the nearest power of 3, or if you want it to adjust to the nearest *lower* power of 3. Basically it comes to: how you handle `1.50E+05`? Should it be `150.00E+03` or `0.15E+06`?

## Case 1: nearest lower power of 3

```py
from math import log10,floor

numbers = [1.2e-2, 1.3e-3, 1.5e5, 1.6e6]
    
    
def adjusted_scientific_notation(val,num_decimals=2,exponent_pad=2):
    exponent_template = "{:0>%d}" % exponent_pad
    mantissa_template = "{:.%df}" % num_decimals
    
    order_of_magnitude = floor(log10(abs(val)))
    nearest_lower_third = 3*(order_of_magnitude//3)
    adjusted_mantissa = val*10**(-nearest_lower_third)
    adjusted_mantissa_string = mantissa_template.format(adjusted_mantissa)
    adjusted_exponent_string = "+-"[nearest_lower_third<0] + exponent_template.format(abs(nearest_lower_third))
    return adjusted_mantissa_string+"E"+adjusted_exponent_string

for n in numbers:
    print("{0:.2E} -> {1: >10}".format(n,adjusted_scientific_notation(n)))
```

which prints out:

```
1.20E-02 ->  12.00E-03
1.30E-03 ->   1.30E-03
1.50E+05 -> 150.00E+03
1.60E+06 ->   1.60E+06
```

## Case 2: nearest power of 3

```py
def adjusted_scientific_notation(val,num_decimals=2,exponent_pad=2):
    exponent_template = "{:0>%d}" % exponent_pad
    mantissa_template = "{:.%df}" % num_decimals
    
    order_of_magnitude = floor(log10(abs(val)))
    nearest_third = 3*(order_of_magnitude//3+int(order_of_magnitude%3==2))
    adjusted_mantissa = val*10**(-nearest_third)
    adjusted_mantissa_string = mantissa_template.format(adjusted_mantissa)
    adjusted_exponent_string = "+-"[nearest_third<0] + exponent_template.format(abs(nearest_third))
    return adjusted_mantissa_string+"E"+adjusted_exponent_string

for n in numbers:
    print("{0:.2E} -> {1: >10}".format(n,adjusted_scientific_notation(n)))
```

which prints out:

```
1.20E-02 ->  12.00E-03
1.30E-03 ->   1.30E-03
1.50E+05 ->   0.15E+06
1.60E+06 ->   1.60E+06
```